# How do I retrieve rows from mysql into a php/html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

[This is the php/html table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drUHc.png)

The invigilator column is where I want the row from mysql db to fill up but the output keeps repeating the same name.
What I want is that the output should be like this
Mr A
Mr B
Mr C
Mr D
Mr A
Mr B
Mr C
Mr D
if we have only 4 names in the database (i.e list the names in ASC order and repeat it again and again).
This is my php/html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <caption>Timetable with number of students</caption>
         <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>No. Students</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Invigilator</th>
                <!-- <th>Edit/Del</th> -->
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                <?php
                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    extract($row);
                    include('includes/shuffle.php');
                    while ($snm = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    $snm1 = $snm["snm_pdo"];
                ?>
           <tr>
           <?php echo "<td>{$id_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$snb_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$cos_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$dat_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$starttim_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$endtim_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$ven_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$dur_pdo}</td>" ?>
           <?php echo "<td>{$snm1}</td>" ?>

            </tr>
         <?php
                    }
                    }
                ?>
```

And this is my shuffle.php that I included

```
<?php  
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "timetable");
    if(!$con){
        die("Bros db no wan connect o" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }       

$query = "SELECT snm_pdo FROM staff_list ORDER BY snm_pdo ASC, RAND() LIMIT 3";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);mysqli_close($con);?>
```

- [This is the structure of the 2nd table(courses)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRYum.jpg)
  This is the query for the table_courses
  this is inside data.inc_course.php

  class Data{

  ```
  // database connection and table name
  private $conn;
  private $table_name = "courses";
  // private $table_name2 = "staff_list";
  // object properties
  public $id;
  public $snb;
  public $cos;
  public $dat;
  public $starttim;
  public $endtim;
  public $ven;
  public $dur;
  public function __construct($db){
      $this->conn = $db;
  }
  ```

// read products

```
    function readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page){
        $query = "SELECT 
                    *
                FROM 
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                ORDER BY 
                    id_pdo ASC 
                LIMIT 
                    {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Then in my index.php page I have this

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$records_per_page = 5;
$from_record_num = ($records_per_page * $page) - $records_per_page;
include_once 'includes/config.php';
include_once 'includes/data.inc_course.php';
include 'includes/shuffle2.php';
$database = new Config();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$product = new Data($db);
$stmt = $product->readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
?>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); 
$output1 = "
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>";
        echo $output1;
       include('includes/nav.php');
$output2 = "
       <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id='page-wrapper'>
            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                        <h1 class='page-header'>Timetable Details</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->

                    <!-- niyicode -->
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <p>
                        <a class='btn btn-primary' href='courses/add.php' role='button'>Add Course</a>
                        <a class='btn btn-primary fleft' href='staff/add.php' role='button'>Add Staff</a>
                    </p>";
        echo $output2;
        if($num>0){
$output =  "           
        <table class= 'table table-bordered table-hover table-striped'>
            <caption>Timetable with number of students</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>No. Students</th>
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>Venue</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Invigilator</th>
                    <!-- <th>Edit/Del</th> -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    if ($snm = $results->FETCH_ASSOC()) {
    $output .= ' <tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['id_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['snb_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['cos_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['dat_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['starttim_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['endtim_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['ven_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['dur_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$snm["snm_pdo"].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    // Add more here if appropriate .... . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= ' </tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
}
$output .='      </tbody>
    </table>    ';
$results->free();
mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo $output;
$page_dom = "index.php";
include_once 'includes/pagination.inc_course.php';
}else{
?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <strong>Warning!</strong> No Data. Please add data to view timetable
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
<?php   
$output5 = "                       </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    ";
        echo $output5;
?>
<!-- echo $output;                     -->
    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

This is the file shuffle2.php that am using for staff_list table query

```
<?php  
    define('dbname', 'timetable');
    define('dbuserid', 'root');
    define('dbpasswd', '');
    define('dbhost', 'localhost');
    define('dbport', '3306');
    define('dbsocket', '');
    define('LBRK','<br />');

    // Connect to database
    $mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost, dbuserid, dbpasswd, dbname, dbport, dbsocket);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error.LBRK;
     exit(1);
    }

    $query1 = "SELECT snm_pdo FROM staff_list ORDER BY snm_pdo ASC, RAND() ";

    $results = $mysqli->query($query1);
    // if ($results===false) {
    //     // Query failed
    //     echo "Failed to read the database table ''<br />" .LBRK;
    //     exit(1);
    // }


    ?>
```

Comment: I would never place an `include` inside a loop

Comment: This is totally wrong! 
`include` with `mysqli` inside `while` loop & `PDO statement`.

Comment: don't mind my code am still a newbie, but I can do better if you show me how. Thanks

Comment: @user3815772 could You please show `query` for this statement:
`row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Comment: @ZeJur function readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page){
  $query = "SELECT 
     *
    FROM 
     " . $this->table_name . "
    ORDER BY 
     id_pdo ASC 
    LIMIT 
     {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help…

```
<?php  
    define('dbname', 'timetable');
    define('dbuserid', 'root');
    define('dbpasswd', '******');
    define('dbhost', 'localhost');
    define('dbport', '3306');
    define('dbsocket', '');
    define('LBRK','<br />');

    // Connect to database
    $mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost, dbuserid, dbpasswd, dbname, dbport, dbsocket);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error.LBRK;
     exit(1);
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM staff_list ORDER BY snm_pdo ASC, RAND() LIMIT 3";

    $results = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($results===false) {
        // Query failed
        echo "Failed to read the database table 'staff_list'<br />" .LBRK;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Process data

    $output = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en\">
    <head>

    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"> 

    <title>Courses List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class=\"table table-bordered table-hover table-striped\">
            <caption>Timetable with number of students</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>No. Students</th>
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>Venue</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Invigilator</th>
                    <!-- <th>Edit/Del</th> -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output .= ' <tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['id_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['snb_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['cos_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['dat_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['starttim_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['endtim_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['ven_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['dur_pdo'].'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    // Add more here if appropriate .... . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= ' </tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
$output .="      </tbody>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
";

$results->free();
mysqli_close($mysqli);

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but am still having issues. Actually I have two different tables am displaying all data from one table while am picking just one row (invigilator) from the second row. Presently the first table showing all data shows only one input repeatedly based on the LIMIT in the second query

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more: what is the structure of the 2nd table (we know more or less "staff_list")? What are the 2 queries you are using? What is the link between the 2 tables (e.g. entry from table 2 shown when user clicks an entry in table 1, key = Invigilator)?

Comment: Please I have edited the question please read again from the bullet thanks.

Comment: Wow! this is working after some tweaking through the code, just like I wanted it to work. Stack Overflow is the best

Comment: :-)) You might want to accept my answer, don't you?

Comment: Please am still on this project but I actually want to add range to the name of invigilators, such that if I have 0-50 students offering a course the number of invigilator will be 1, 51-100=2, 101-150=3 etc help put please

Comment: Isn't **snb_pdo** the database item you are looking for? So, what is the problem you have?

Comment: you remember that invigilator name was fetch from another table called "staff_list" while the others were fetched from the table "courses". What am saying now is that I want to fetch invigilators from staff_list based on the number of students(which am fetching from another table(courses). I don't know how to go about such query

Comment: You should modify the query statement such as **SELECT * FROM courses c, staff_list s WHERE s.snm_pdo = c.snm_pdo ORDER BY s.snm_pdo ASC;** This would join the 2 tables. Note: I assume that the staff key is **snm_pdo** in both the tables (since I do not know the structure of the tables).